# Kafka JsonDeserializer fails. What to do?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, deserialization

I just want to know what is the best approach to handle json deserialisation errors while consuming data.

Lets say, my producer added below Json to topic:

```
{ "name":"John", "age":30 }
```

Later on producer changed the format of Json and now it started to add below message:

```
{ "surname":"Smith", "Country":"USA", "car":null }
```

On the other side I have Consumer which has Pojo with the fields name and age. Obviously my consumer(JsonDeserializer) is going to fail while deserialising second message.

Here is the question, how should I handle those kind of schema changes on the code side ? 
PreConditions:

- I don't want to just log error or send those undeserilised messages
  to other topic.
- I don't want to use Avro.
- Only JsonDeserializer is allowed

Maybe the main question should be "if it is possible to save schemas of my Json messages to topic so that later if the format of message changes I would know how to deserialise them"

Comment: @maz Question says don't want to use Avro

Comment: The only way I've seen this handled is to explicitly place some field that's always present (like "type" or an actual embedded schema object), then use byte array deserializer plus a if-else check in the consumer loop for each possible event type when trying to deserialize to a POJO

Comment: We have put in place a solution like the one proposed by @cricket_007 : we added some metadata to the Json payload: `{"payloadType":"Person", "version":1.0, data: { "name":"John", "age":30 }}` and `{"payloadType":"Person", "version":2.0, data: { "surname":"Smith", "Country":"USA", "car":null }}`

Comment: I would also recommend the approach mentioned by @val. So that you can always fetch the schema associated to that json event

Comment: Thank you all for responses. 
Does it mean that I will also add different Pojo's depending on the version ?
class Person{
Sting type:
String version;
String name;
Integer  age;
}

class Person{
Sting type:
String version;
String surname;
String Country ;
Car car;
}

and depending on version and type I will deserilise message with proper POJO ?

Comment: What You guys think about. Replaying all messages if the schema changes ?
So whoever produces those messages had to produce all messages once again .(recreate topic or sent retention policy)

This way I will have only one Pojo but it has the drawback of always replaying and coordination between teams (previous also needs coordination but this needs more I guess)

Comment: Why don't you want to use Avro?

Comment: I just want to understand if there are some guys who managed to take care if schema changes without using Avro, This question is more like knowing about people thoughts about this versioning using Json.

Comment: @sinan about your question ... `Person{ Sting type: String version; String name; Integer age; }` .... (The way we did it, in fact, we do not use POJO: we work with JsonNode objects.) But in your case, I would not include the type nor the version in the Person POJO. I would rather have a first step to analyze the type and the version, and based on these values choose the POJO you will use to deserialize the "data". Create classes PersonV1 and PersonV2 ? Or if your new version of the Pojo is retro-compatible, you can keep one version of the Pojo and play with several deserializers....

Comment: @sinan About `Replaying all messages if the schema changes ?` (you meant `publish again all messages`?) I really do not like this idea. 1. you cannot guarantee that all the publishers will be able to regenerate all the messages. 2. I believe the advantage of tools like Kafka is to decouple producers and consumers. 3.It's normal in the life cycle of a project to have evolution in the schema of objects. If consumers need to consume old messages, they have to adapt (and ignoring them is a totally valid option).

Comment: An alternative to the solution you proposed would be to write a KS app which consumes the topic, transform the `v.N` objects into `v.N+1` objects. But I do not like this concept. IMO, once a message is written in a permanent storage it should remain as-is (i am a big fan of event sourcing ^^).