# Can we channel different kind of message through same kafka topic?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have scenario where I have different type of messages to be streamed from kafka producer.

If I dont want to use different topic per different message type how to handle it at spark-structured-streaming consumer side ?

```
i.e. only one topic I want to use for different type of messages ...say Student record , Customer record....etc.
How to identify which message is been received from Kafka topic?

Please let me know how to handle this scenario at kafka consumer side?
```

Comment: The producer and the consumer need to agree on a way to identify the content of the messages. You can add an attribute "type" to describe what the message is about. A similar discussion happened recently in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191872/kafka-jsondeserializer-fails-what-to-do . The discussion was more about Json, but you may find some ideas which could be applied to your case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this by adding "some attribute" to the message itself when producing which signifies a logical topic, or operation, and differentiating on the Spark side - e.g. Structured Streaming KAFKA integration. E.g. checking the message content for "some attribute" and process accordingly.

Partitioning is used of course for ordering always.

Comment: assume I have two messages like Student class & Employee class ... how can I handle them at consumer side ? please provide some snippet...thank you.

Comment: @cricket_007. The comment not the question. To be honest it’s a bit hot here. So I will leave to you

Answer (score 2):

Kafka topics don't inheriently have "types of data". It's all bytes, so yes you can serialize completely separate objects into the same topic, but consumers must then add logic to know what are all possible types will get added into the topic.

That being said, Structured Streaming is built on the idea of having structured data with a schema, so it likely will not work if you had completely different types in the same topic without at least performing a filter first based on some inner attribute that is always present among all types.

Comment: thank you... so without some inner attribute/flag it can be done ...can you please provide some pseduo code for cosumer ?

Comment: I haven't done it, really... But assuming you have data as JSON, then you would first `CAST(value AS STRING)`, then from there, you would have to parse the JSON using `get_json_object` functions, and finally do something like `val someTypes = df.where($"attribute" == "some-type")` to filter out those specific events

Comment: Like I said, though, structured streaming requires a schema at some point. If you don't have consistent data, you might just have to use the DStream,RDD consumer

Comment: so if I have two entities like Student extends IEntity   and Employee extends IEntity , Do I need to have parent Entity i.e. class ParentMessage { String type , IEntity Entity}  ..is it correct way ? At consumer side i get ParentMessage  then parse it back... will that work ? or do you foresee any issues ?